# Linq version of SQL "IN" statement

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following 3 tables as part of a simple "item tagging" schema:

==Items==

- ItemId  int
- Brand  varchar
- Name  varchar
- Price  money
- Condition  varchar
- Description  varchar
- Active  bit

==Tags==

- TagId  int
- Name  varchar
- Active  bit

==TagMap==

- TagMapId  int
- TagId  int (fk)
- ItemId  int (fk)
- Active  bit

I want to write a LINQ query to bring back Items that match a list of tags (e.g. TagId = 2,3,4,7).  In my application context, examples of items would be "Computer Monitor", "Dress Shirt", "Guitar", etc. and examples of tags would be "electronics", "clothing", etc.  I would normally accomplish this with a SQL IN Statement.

Comment: Why the inner join is not prefered here? You know if the Context.TagMaps contains 10 records , it will iterate 36 times in background , irrespective of the fact that whether there is a match or not.

Comment: You may find [SQL queries in LINQ](http://www.codeducky.org/sql-queries-in-linq/#where-in) helpful.  It's a list of common SQL queries represented in LINQ.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Something like

```
var TagIds = new int[] {12, 32, 42};

var q = from map in Context.TagMaps 
        where TagIds.Contains(map.TagId)
        select map.Items;
```

should do what you need. This will generate an In ( 12, 32, 42 ) clause (or more specifically a parameterized IN clause if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: it comes into play through the select map.Item part. In SQL you would have to join the TagMap to the Item table. Linq does that for you because of the relationship from TagMap to Item. You are essentially saying "find all TagMaps that reference any of my TagIds and return me their item".

This Linq query is the same as the following SQL:

SELECT Items.* 
FROM TagMaps INNER JOIN Items ON Item.ItemId = TagMap.ItemId
WHERE TagMaps.TagId IN (12,32,24) 

Linq takes care of the INNER JOIN part for you, because it knows how to go from TagMap to Item.

Comment: Why the inner join is not prefered here? You know if the `Context.TagMaps` contains 10 records , it will iterate 36 times in background , irrespective of the fact that whether there is a match or not.

Comment: The array declaration isn't quite right.  Combine this answer with @LukeSchafer's answer below and it will work.

Answer (score 16):

given array of items:

```
var list = new int[] {2,3,4}
```

use:

```
where list.Contains(tm.TagId)
```

Comment: I don't understand how that would work given the 3 table schema I have.

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] names = {"John", "Cassandra", "Sarah"};

var results = (from n in db.Names
               where names.Contains(n.Name)
               select n).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<int> tagIds = new List<int>() {2, 3, 4, 7};
int tagIdCount = tagIds.Count;
    //
// Items that have any of the tags
//  (any item may have any of the tags, not necessarily all of them
    //
var ItemsAnyTags = db.Items
  .Where(item => item.TagMaps
    .Any(tm => tagIds.Contains(tm.TagId))
  );

    //
// Items that have ALL of the tags
//  (any item may have extra tags that are not mentioned).
    //
var ItemIdsForAllTags = db.TagMap
  .Where(tm => tagIds.Contains(tm.TagId))
  .GroupBy(tm => tm.ItemId)
  .Where(g => g.Count() == tagIdCount)
  .Select(g => g.Key);
    //
var ItemsWithAllTags = db.Items
  .Where(item => ItemsIdsForAllTags.Contains(item.ItemId));

//runs just one query against the database
List<Item> result = ItemsWithAllTags.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use,

```
var TagIds = {12, 32, 42}
var prod =entities.TagMaps.Where(tagmaps=> TagIds .Contains(tagmaps.TagId));
```

Answer (score 1):

You may create an extension method "IN()"

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static bool IN(this object anyObject, params object[] list)
    { return list.Contains(anyObject); }
}
```

to be used like this

```
var q = from map in Context.TagMaps 
        where map.TagId.IN(2, 3, 4, 7)
        select map.Items;
```

Or just use the inline array.Contains() notation:

```
var q = from map in Context.TagMaps 
        where new[]{2, 3, 4, 7}.Contains(map.TagId)
        select map.Items;
```