# Linq-to-SQL equivalent of SQL "in" statement

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linq version of SQL “IN” statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896123/linq-version-of-sql-in-statement)

I want to implement the SQL "in" logic using Linq to SQL.  How can I do that?