# What's the syntax for this linq expression calling the in method

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have to query a repository where column a = {myvalue} and column b has any value in a collection.

Here's what I have:

```
Application[] applicationCollection = GetAllApplications();
var result = repo.GetAll(r => r.Email == myEmail && r.Application.In(applicationCollection));
```

I can't figure out how to write the "in" part...

Preferrably links to how to do this would be best, so I can learn it, as opposed to just getting the answer :). Thanks all.

(I'm sure this is a repeat question, but my Google/search skills are obviously poor.)

Comment: Are you saying that you know when `applicationCollection` *contains* `r.Application`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL idea of `item in collection` is written in C# (including LINQ) as `collection.Contains(item)`.  In your example, this might be:

```
var result = repo.GetAll(r => r.Email == myEmail &&
               applicationCollection.Contains(r.Application));
```

Comment: If it's as easy as this, I feel extremely stupid. Will try when I get back to work tomorrow, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
ApplicationCollection.Contains(r.Application)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.Contains(collection)` instead of `in`.  [Here's a link since you wanted one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896123/linq-version-of-sql-in-statement)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write it the way you've shown, you can write this extension method:

```
public static bool In<T>(this T item, IEnumerable<T> set)
{
    return set.Contains(item);
}
```

And then use it **exactly** like you did in your question:

```
Application[] applicationCollection = GetAllApplications();
var result = repo.GetAll(r =>
    r.Email == myEmail &&
    r.Application.In(applicationCollection));
```

This will work fine if you're only working with in-memory sets.  If you're doing something like LINQ-to-SQL, however, this won't be compatible.

*Note: I'm not trying to imply that this extension method might be a good idea to use - I'm just saying it's possible to write one like that.*