# Linq to strongly typed DataTable and Null issue for date column

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

Here is my code

```
 Dim dr2 As PBRuleData.PBRuleRow
                        Dim query As IEnumerable(Of PBRuleData.PBRuleRow) = From s In Me.PBRule.PBRule.AsEnumerable() _
                                                                            Where s.PBRuleId = .PBRuleId And s.StartDate <= .PBDate _
                                                                            And (s.IsFinishDateNull Or (s.FinishDate > .PBDate)) Select s

                        If query.Count > 0 Then
                            dr2 = query.ElementAt(0)
                            If Not (dr2.IsHoursNull) Then
                                If dr2.IsBilling Then
                                    dblHoursBILL += CType(dr2.Hours, Double)
                                Else
                                    dblHoursPAY += CType(dr2.Hours, Double)
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
```

Even though I have put s.IsFinishDateNull condition to avoid null exception but its still causing exception `The value for column 'FinishDate' in table 'PBRule' is DBNull.`
this linq query is an alternate to this datatable query which works fine.

```
Dim dr As DataRow()
                        Dim sQuery As String
                        sQuery = "PBRuleId={0} AND StartDate<=#{1:MM/dd/yy}# AND (FinishDate>=#{1:MM/dd/yy}# OR FinishDate IS NULL)"
                        dr = Me.PBRule.PBRule.Select(String.Format(sQuery, .PBRuleId, .PBDate))

                        If dr.Length > 0 Then
                            If Not (dr(0).Item("Hours") Is DBNull.Value) Then
                                If dr(0).Item("IsBilling").ToString().ToLower = "true" Then
                                    dblHoursBILL += CType(dr(0).Item("Hours").ToString(), Double)
                                Else
                                    dblHoursPAY += CType(dr(0).Item("Hours").ToString(), Double)
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
```

Can anyone help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `OrElse` instead of `Or`.

`Or` operator evaluates both sides of the expressions regardless of the result of the left hand side.

Comment: Thanks this worked. can u also help me to convert this sql  to linq select * from tblPBRule where PBRuleId = 364 and StartDate < = '20140902' and finishdate is null and PBCodeid  in (select PBCodeid from tblpbrule where PBHourstypeid IN (3,4,5,6)) or shall i ask another  question on so

Comment: You're welcome. If you are struggling with `IN` clause, see [Linq version of SQL “IN” statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896123/linq-version-of-sql-in-statement/896156#896156). Or better create a new question.